# APNS invalid payload size

Tags: notifications, apple-push-notifications, push, payload

my certificates and provisioning profiles have expired and I just renewed it. However, when I tried the push notification, I now get an "Invalid payload size" error. The message I sent was a simple "Test message" but I get an invalid payload size. What could this mean?

Comment: What is your code for sending the notification?

Comment: I'm using APNS-PHP. Here's the line of code: $send_result = $this->apn->sendMessage($deviceToken, $message, $badge, $sound);

Comment: check this answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699715/apple-push-notification-limits