# Apple disconnected me because of invalid tokens

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I try to send multiple notifications with one hit. Many users have more than one device and i put their device tokens into an array. It is working fine but if there is a wrong token Apple is disconnecting me and the device with working token gets no push notification. I've read about a error-response-solution at this post: [Apple Push Notification Limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699715/apple-push-notification-limits)

But this solution is not working for me. It says: Status:7-Invalid payload size.
But there is only the message "test" and I'm sure the reason is the wrong token. How could I continue the foreach script without disconnecting?

```
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = array('WRONG_TOKEN', 'WORKING_TOKEN');

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'PASS';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = "test";

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'cer.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => "www/sound.mp3",
    'content-available' => 1,
    'badge' => 1
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

//foreach für array
                    foreach($deviceToken as $token){
                    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $token) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;


                    // Send it to the server
                    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

                    }//foreach end

                    if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

//checkAppleErrorResponse($fp);

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: try and use [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php). what does var_dump($result); exit; do?